# Apache Server 2.4 on EC2 "caught SIGTERM shutting down "

Tags: amazon-ec2, ddos, apache2.4, sigterm

I'm using amazon linux on an m3.large instance on EC2.
I had these logs before my apache server was shut down:

```
[Sun Sep 28 18:54:31.679261 2014] [cgi:error] [pid 32422] [client 67.211.230.58:58937] 
      script not  found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/wlogin.cgi

[Mon Sep 29 03:32:17.602213 2014] [cgi:error] [pid 13612] [client 173.45.100.18:42591] 
      attempt to invoke directory as script: /var/www/cgi-bin/

[Mon Sep 29 03:32:19.142561 2014] [cgi:error] [pid 13623] [client 173.45.100.18:43455] 
      script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/hi

[Mon Sep 29 15:40:45.599504 2014] [core:error] [pid 17852] [client 80.82.64.145:51226] 
      AH00126: Invalid URI in request GET  HTTP/1.1

[Mon Sep 29 22:53:46.532859 2014] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 10800]
      AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
```

And.. that's it. My httpd service was shut down.

What I'm smelling here is that some people are trying to access the server by executing CGI scripts with GET request which I found to suspect in this line:

> script not found or unable to stat: /var/www/cgi-bin/hi

Here what the hell the "hi" supposed to mean unless it's not an exploiting attempt?

Also:

> attempt to invoke directory as script: /var/www/cgi-bin/

They all are coming from thge same ip, 173.45.100.18.

Am I under DDoS and other malicious attack, or something arcane going on?

Comment: I asked this same question on Serverfault but seems no one found it interesting.. So I've got no answer for 2 hours!